# How can I group items and add label to each group in CheckedListBox in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `CheckedListBox` control to display categorized items in my application. I can add items to the list but cannot categorize them. To be more specific, I want to group items and add a `category label` to each group.

Currently I am using `SqlDataReader` to add items to the control.

Can anyone help me get around this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a inbuilt option to group items in `CheckedListBox` but you can try with `ListView` with [`CheckBoxes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) property set as `true`.  ListView is supporting for grouping as well.

[How to: Group Items in a Windows Forms ListView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Damith for your reply. I really didn't work with ListView control ever. However, I will give it a try.

Comment: Alternatively: TreeView + TreeView.CheckBoxes = true